# How to check if a given data exists in onther table MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySql Database:

1. Captain(captain.email)
2. Members(member.email)

I want when captain table insert data in captain.email then check If members table data in members.email are already exit then data in captain.email not insert in captain table.

How it is possible ?

1.Captain :

```
CREATE TABLE `captain` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`username_canonical` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email_canonical` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`expires_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`confirmation_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`password_requested_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`roles` longtext NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
`credentials_expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`credentials_expire_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8` (`username_canonical`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF` (`email_canonical`)
)
```

2.Members :

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fos_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
UNIQUE KEY `email_2` (`email`),
KEY `IDX_45A0D2FF296CD8AE` (`team_id`),
KEY `IDX_45A0D2FF8C20A0FB` (`fos_user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_45A0D2FF296CD8AE` FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`) REFERENCES `team` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_45A0D2FF8C20A0FB` FOREIGN KEY (`fos_user_id`) REFERENCES `fos_user`   (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Look at triggers, you want a before insert trigger on the captain table.

Comment: @Seth McClaine: 1. how would you cancel insert in case if the email already exists? 2. How would you guarantee the requirement in case if 2 queries run simultaneously?

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Can say more about the tables, relationships, and input data?

Comment: @paul I have two different tables first Captain and Second captain team members. In my project first captain come and register through our email id and then create members. member name , member email etc...I want if any email id are exit in member table then it is not create same eamil id in captain table.

Comment: @KunwarSiddharthSingh What if a captain of team A is a member on team B? :(

Comment: @paul No, captain of team A and members of team A,B,C... if he is a member then he is not create to his self as captain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce such constraint.

Using declarative referential integrity (DRI) you could create a table that contains all of the columns that you need to build a unique key on.